# React Native / Laravel - Sending a request to API

Tags: json, laravel, react-native

I'm implementing an mobile application that uses Laravel as an API to communicate with a database.

I want to send a username and password from my react native application to Laravel. I am using the following code to do so:

```
    fetch("mysite.com/api/login", {method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify({username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password})})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            this.handleLogin(responseData);

        })
        .done();
  }
```

But this uses `JSON.stringify` to send across the data. But how do I handle that inside my Laravel application? Currently, I am accepting the data by:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
     $username = $request->get('username');
}
```

However, this is obviously not working since the data being sent is in JSON format. So inside PHP, do I need to decode the JSON parameter?

Comment: What version of Laravel? You should be able to do $request->username.
Can you show us a dump of the request?

Comment: @daniel - this is larabel 5 .. And nope when I do a post request with my app it returns false BUT when I do a post request through postman it returns true using the same details

Comment: That's really odd. Sounds like there might be some sort of permissions issue, but the Postman thing seems to negate that. Are you able to query your db at all from your app?

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting output from postman then there is an issue in the fetching part else try
`public function login(Request $request)
{
     $username = $request-> username;
}`