# Develop a react native mobile application with laravel backend

Tags: android, laravel, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to develop a react native mobile application with Laravel backend. Since i developed a completed websites which using Laravel framework. It could be great with mobile apps too. I know this is possible if using Laravel API. But i am trying to find some tutorial to start but so far i haven't found yet. First should begin with login & register pages. Any recommended here?

Answer (score 0):

It did not matter your API is Laravel or etc.
The things that matter is your API should be a RESTful Web Service.

[Check this page for how to do a network request in react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can start with https://github.com/bartonhammond/snowflake/
It does have basic Account features, but it does not use a Laravel API. You can get the Snowflake running to understand the React-native part.

Thereafter you can make your own API endpoints with laravel, and change the snowflake code accordingly. I have been exactly at your spot a year ago. Hit me on twitter if anything else you wanna ask.

Answer (score 0):

just use fetch method to get json data from your laravel APIs
following link help you lot
[React Native / Laravel - Sending a request to API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542162/react-native-laravel-sending-a-request-to-api)